# Output the object in javascript with fb sdk

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

hey guys am new to javascript fb development.i have just came to learn about the `FB.API`. But when i tried to output the object in facebook javascript sdk it didnt ouput anything.

MY CODE

```
var body = 'Reading JS SDK documentation';
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response) {
if (!response || response.error) {
alert('Error occured');


} else {
console.log( response.message);


}

});
```

But when i tried this code it shows `error occured`.I know `/me/feed'` returns the post id in json format and what i need is to output the `message` object to the console. ie `Reading JS SDK documentation`.

Can it be done with fb js sdk ..if yes please help me in doing this ..Any help would be appreciated.Thanks